# JavaScript's Event Loop and Browser Rendering Quirks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, dom, browser

I recently stumbled upon an interesting behavior in JavaScript that got me curious and I thought it might interest others here.

### The Scenario:

I was working on a React project where I needed to use `ResizeObserver` to monitor changes in the size of certain DOM elements. The issue I faced was `TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'ResizeObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'`. This error occurred because the elements I was trying to observe were not yet in the DOM at the time the observer was instantiated.

### The Solution That Puzzled Me:

After trying different approaches, I found that wrapping the observer initialization code in `setTimeout(checkAndObserve, 0)` mysteriously fixed the issue. Interestingly, executing `checkAndObserve` directly without `setTimeout` did not work, even though in theory, `setTimeout` with a delay of 0ms should execute the function basically (but not really) immediately.

### The Underlying Mechanics:

This phenomenon got me thinking about the JavaScript event loop and the rendering process in browsers. As far as I understand, when `setTimeout` is used, even with a delay of 0ms, it places the `checkAndObserve` function in the event queue. This means it will only execute after the current stack is clear. This slight delay, as transient as it seems, allows the browser to complete any pending rendering tasks – in my case, rendering the DOM elements that `ResizeObserver` needs to observe.

This is different from a direct `checkAndObserve` call, which executes immediately, not giving the browser that tiny window to catch up with DOM updates.

### I still got a few open questions:

1. **Event Loops:** How exactly does the JavaScript event loop handle these `setTimeout` calls with 0ms delays, and how does this interplay with browser rendering cycles?
2. **Best Practices:** In situations like this, is using `setTimeout` with a 0ms delay considered a best practice or a necessary "hack"? Are there more elegant ways to ensure that DOM elements are available for manipulation or observation?
3. **Performance Implications:** Could this method have any negative impact on performance, especially in complex applications with multiple such timeouts?
4. **Alternatives in React:** For fellow React developers, are there more React-centric solutions to this problem, considering the framework's process and component lifecycle?

I'm really interested to hear your thoughts on this and if any of yall ever had a similar problem.

Comment: [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/779379)

Comment: @VLAZ oh wow that's an oldschool post, but yes exactly what I meant 